# How to fix json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json

Tried installing something from GitHub and I always get this error. any methods on how to fix this one? thank you so much!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pyinstalive", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyinstalive==3.1.6', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstalive')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyinstalive/startup.py", line 321, in run
    pil.ig_api = auth.authenticate(username=pil.ig_user, password=pil.ig_pass)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyinstalive/auth.py", line 92, in authenticate
    json.loads(e.error_response).get("error_title", e.error_response)))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: The main problem here is that the authentication is failing, and apparently nothing is present in `error_response`, which, when being decoded, is throwing this error

Comment: @VigneshBayariR. any ways to fix this error?

Comment: Verify the username and password you've provided

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in pSMAC, where different multitasking jobs try to access a file, while another process has a lock on that same file. See [issue 591](https://github.com/automl/SMAC3/issues/591) of AutoML.